# Pandas DataFrame: Fill NaN values based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently wrangling a big data set of 2 mio rows from Lyft for a Udacity project. The DataFrame looks like this:

```
     id             name             latitude    longitude
0   148.0   Horton St at 40th St     37.829705  -122.287610
1   376.0   Illinois St at 20th St   37.760458  -122.387540
2   453.0   Brannan St at 4th St     37.777934  -122.396973
3   182.0   19th Street BART Station 37.809369  -122.267951
4   237.0   Fruitvale BART Station   37.775232  -122.224498
5   NaN     NaN                      37.775232  -122.224498
```

As I try to express in the last line, I have a lot of NaN values for `id` and `name`, however, `latitude` and `longitude` are mostly never empty. My assumption is that I could actually extract the `name` from other rows given a certain combination of `latitude` and `longitude`.

Once I have the name, I would try filling the NaN values for `id` using `name`

```
dict_id = dict(zip(df['name'], df['id']))
df['id'] = df['id'].fillna(df['name'].map(dict_id))
```

However, I struggle because with `latitude` and `longitude` I have two values to match against the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can left merge the dataframe with the copy of it after dropna , then rename the columns:

```
m = df.merge(df.dropna(subset=['name']),on=['latitude','longitude'],
                                       how='left',suffixes=('','_y'))
out = (m.drop(['id','name'],1).rename(columns={'id_y':'id','name_y':'name'})
        .reindex(df.columns,axis=1))
```

---

```
      id                      name   latitude   longitude
0  148.0      Horton St at 40th St  37.829705 -122.287610
1  376.0    Illinois St at 20th St  37.760458 -122.387540
2  453.0      Brannan St at 4th St  37.777934 -122.396973
3  182.0  19th Street BART Station  37.809369 -122.267951
4  237.0    Fruitvale BART Station  37.775232 -122.224498
5  237.0    Fruitvale BART Station  37.775232 -122.224498
```